# Python remove sentence if it is at start of string and starts with specific words?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings that looks like:

```
docs = ['Hi, my name is Eric. Are you blue?',
        "Hi, I'm ! What is your name?", 
        'This is a great idea. I would love to go.', 
        'Hello, I am Jane Brown. What is your name?', 
        "Hello, I am a doctor! Let's go to the mall.",
        'I am ready to go. Mom says hello.']
```

I want to remove the first sentence of a string if it starts with 'Hi' or 'Hello'.

Desired Output:

```
docs = ['Are you blue?',
        'What is your name?', 
        'This is a great idea. I would love to go.', 
        'What is your name?', 
        "Let's go to the mall."
        'I am ready to go. Mom says hello.']
```

The regex I have is:

```
re.match('.*?[a-z0-9][.?!](?= )', x))
```

But this only give be the first sentence in weird format like:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 41), match='Hi, my name is Eric.'>
```

What can I do to get my desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can  use

```py
docs = [re.sub(r'^H(?:ello|i)\b.*?[.?!]\s+', '', doc) for doc in docs]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ixXQU1/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `H(?:ello|i)\b` - `Hello` or `Hi` word (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `[.?!]` - a `.`, `?` or `!`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7eFAnA):

```py
import re
docs = ['Hi, my name is Eric. Are you blue?',
        "Hi, I'm ! What is your name?", 
        'This is a great idea. I would love to go.', 
        'Hello, I am Jane Brown. What is your name?', 
        "Hello, I am a doctor! Let's go to the mall.",
        'I am ready to go. Mom says hello.']
docs = [re.sub(r'^H(?:ello|i)\b.*?[.?!]\s+', '', doc) for doc in docs]
print(docs)
```

Output:

```
[
    'Are you blue?',
    'What is your name?',
    'This is a great idea. I would love to go.',
    'What is your name?',
    "Let's go to the mall.",
    'I am ready to go. Mom says hello.'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to first split the string in sentences

```
splitted_docs = []
for str in docs:
    splitted_docs.append(str.split('.'))
```

Then, you want to check each sentence for Hi or Hello with your regex and add it to the final array

```
final_docs = []
for str in splitted_docs:
    final_sentence = []
    for sentence in str:
        if not re.match('.*?[a-z0-9][.?!](?= )', sentence):
            final_sentence.append(sentence)
    final_docs.append(final_sentence.join('.'))
```

Actually, your regex is not working, just changed the code to make it work, i goes just like follows:

```
for str in splitted_docs:

    final_sentence = []
    for sentence in str:
        if not 'Hello' in sentence and not 'Hi' in sentence:
            final_sentence.append(sentence)
    final_docs.append('.'.join(final_sentence))
```

Finally, filter your array to remove all the empty strings that may have been created in the process of joining:

```
final_docs = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', final_docs))
print(final_docs)
```

Output:

```
[' Are you blue?', 'This is a great idea. I would love to go.', ' What is your name?', 'I am ready to go. Mom says hello.']
```

I'll leave the full code here, any suggestion is welcome, I am sure this can be solved in a more functional approach that may be easier to understand, but I am not familiar with it to such a level.

```
import re
docs = ['Hi, my name is Eric. Are you blue?',
        "Hi, I'm ! What is your name?", 
        'This is a great idea. I would love to go.', 
        'Hello, I am Jane Brown. What is your name?', 
        "Hello, I am a doctor! Let's go to the mall.",
        'I am ready to go. Mom says hello.']

    
splitted_docs = []
for str in docs:
    splitted_docs.append(str.split('.'))


final_docs = []
for str in splitted_docs:

    final_sentence = []
    for sentence in str:
        if not 'Hello' in sentence and not 'Hi' in sentence:
            final_sentence.append(sentence)
    final_docs.append('.'.join(final_sentence))


final_docs = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', final_docs))
print(final_docs)
```